# Cannot add state to TransactionBuilder after sending it to another party in a flow

Tags: corda

I have a flow where the following happens:

- `PartyA` creates a `TransactionBuilder`
- `PartyA` sends the `TransactionBuilder` to `PartyB`
- `PartyB` adds a state to the `TransactionBuilder`

However, when `PartyB` tries to a state to the builder, they get the following exception:

```
[WARN ] 2018-03-20T16:02:35,932Z [Node thread-1] flow.[99246baf-1a1d-44e5-b2f9-f4eb341b97d4].run - Terminated by unexpected exception {}
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.add(Collections.java:1055) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.addInputState(TransactionBuilder.kt:149) ~[corda-core-corda-3.0.jar:?]
```

What's happening here? Why can't `PartyB` add items to the `TransactionBuilder`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Corda, objects are serialised before being sent over the wire. When deserialising the received objects, it is impossible to detect whether any `List`s that are being deserialised were originally mutable or immutable. On balance, we decided that our serialisation engine should make any `List`s it deserialises immutable, rather than mutable.

This is causing the issue you observe above. Under the hood, you are calling `add` on an immutable list.

You can bypass this issue using `TransactionBuilder.copy` to make a copy of the `TransactionBuilder` that has mutable lists of states again.

Answer (score 1):

Issue only occurs in Corda V3, where round trip serialisation converts mutable objects into non mutable. This is not the case in Corda V2 or lower.